# How to turn a blog into a book?

Tags: wordpress, blog

Does anyone have any experience converting a blog into a book, and if so:

1. What software did you use?
2. How was your experience?

I use Wordpress for my blogging.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Never done this myself, but I just found this site.  Looks promising!

http://www.blurb.com/create/book/blogbook

Good luck!

Comment: I've used it, very happy with the end product.

Comment: @Sean: Could you elaborate on your experience?  How much effort was required to reformat it?  How flexible is it?

Comment: blurb is a great book software, but you have to do all the formatting, pretty manually.

Answer (score 3):

http://blog2print.sharedbook.com/blogworld/printmyblog/index.html

Answer (score 2):

You can use [LaTeX](http://www.latex-project.org/) or [DocBook](http://www.docbook.org/) and copy&paste or a database dump to set up the book.

Comment: If you're not afraid of a little php, you can create a LaTeX template which renders your whole blog into a big document.

Answer (score 2):

I did this for my brother's blog by laboriously cutting-and-pasting text and saving images and re-typesetting everything in LaTeX, and then getting it printed through [Lulu](http://lulu.com/).  Took ages, but the result is a thousand-page tome that looks great.

I've long planned to write a WordPress plugin that would do the bulk of the work (there would still need to be some tweeking, I think), but haven't gotten around to it yet.

Answer (score 2):

Try [Anthologize.](http://anthologize.org/) It's for Wordpress too. :)

According to ReadWriteWeb:

> Anthologize enables anyone working
>   with WordPress to easily publish their
>   content in a variety of book formats,
>   including PDF, ePUB, and TEI, an open
>   XML format. Anthologize can handle
>   WordPress blog content as well as
>   feeds from other sources, allowing
>   these items to be updated, reordered,
>   and edited, and then exported.

Just came out last Aug 3.

Answer (score 1):

I found a similar but easier way than the one described above. in blogspot.com there is an option that let's you download your blog either as a word document or as a pdf, once you select this option and save the file, you have a very good formated document with all the articles in your blog. But still if you want to modify it, like for example adding an index, you can quickly do it in word and save it.
Then you need to convert that file to a pdf, in order to be accepted for printing in lulu.com, which is a fantastic editorial site for independent books, and it is very cheap. It also lets you choose among many kind of papers, page formats, and more.
I think this is the easiest way to transform your blog to a book.